# LinqToSQL - mapping out the DataContext with lots of tables?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I've been working on a project where I have been using `LinqToSQL` that involved a lot of tables. All of these where mapped in one `.dbml` file (i.e. only one `DataContext`). I did this on the pretense that (currently) you cant join across multiple data contexts. For example...

```
DB1DataContext db1 = new DB1DataContext();
DB2DataContext db2 = new DB2DataContext();

var query =
    from x in db1.SomeTable
    join y in db2.AnotherTable on x.Id equals y.Id
    select new
    {
        x.Column,
        y.Column
    };
```

Someone argued that this isn't so, and I should break the `.dbml` file down into seperate smaller (i.e *more* managable) data contexts. I've now just set up an example, run a similar query to the one above and got the following error...

> base {System.SystemException} = {"The
>   query contains references to items
>   defined on a different data context."}

I am curious, am I missing something? What are the common practices where there are a lot of tables that require mapping? How can you break down a .dbml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was asked several times here and there is no definite answer. Check this questions:

- [LINQ to SQL: Multiple / Single .dbml per project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337763/linq-to-sql-multiple-single-dbml-per-project)
- [Are Multiple DataContext classes ever appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949/are-multiple-datacontext-classes-ever-appropriate)
- [Linq to SQL and large DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274996/linq-to-sql-and-large-db-model)
- [Managing LINQ to SQL .dbml model complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200/managing-linq-to-sql-dbml-model-complexity)
- [Best Practices for Managing Linq to SQL Dbml Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664/best-practices-for-managing-linq-to-sql-dbml-files)

Some answers refer to this blog post: [Lifetime of a LINQ to SQL DataContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/04/27/lifetime-of-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx)