# Linq to Sql Data class in dbml

Tags: database, linq-to-sql

I am abit curious about dbml.... Should I create one dbml file for one database or separated into different parts e.g. User dbml (only tables relate to users) etc? When I do this I will have abit of problems. Assume the User dbml has a User table and if the Order dbml has a User table as well, this won't be allowed if the entity namespace are the same. If I have set a different entity namespace for each of the dbml, it works but this will gives me a different entity of User table. When a single data returns to Business Logic layer, there is a difficulty of knowing which entity namespace of the user table to be used.

If I built one dbml file instead of having separate dbml, will single dbml appear slower than the separated dbml version when fetching the data from the database.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127283/linqtosql-mapping-out-the-datacontext-with-lots-of-tables

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL is designed to be operated with a single Data Context object.

Lifetime of a LINQ to SQL DataContext
http://blogs.msdn.com/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/04/27/lifetime-of-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx

The NerdDinner tutorial has a pretty good example of typical Linq to SQL usage, using a repository pattern.  In all cases, the repository objects use a single Data Context object to perform the work:

[**http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm**](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm)

What you are trying to do sounds like it might be more suitable for the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx).  Be advised, however, that the Entity Framework has some issues in its present release, particularly with regards to lazy loading.